# Example of game colors in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

[How can you put names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTz3J.png)

Make sure if you put names on the text dynamic and the rest of the colors

This is a game about colors where the name of the color will appear on top and you have to try to guess which color you will have 3 lives

```
  stop();

 //var and text information
  texto.text = "Vermelho";
  var vidas  = 3;
  vida.text = "Vidas: " + vidas;

  //buttons function to be pressed
  vermelho.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clicked);
  Azul.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clicked1);
  Verde.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clicked2);
  Amarelo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clicked3);
  Rosa.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clicked4);
  Laranja.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clicked5);

 //function to validate if the text is equal to the button
function clicked(clickInfo){

//If click on red go to blue
if(clickInfo.target == vermelho){
    trace("Correto");
    texto.text = "Azul";
    vermelho.visible = false;
}else{
    vidaa();
    vida.text = "Vidas: " + vidas;
    trace("Incorecto");
}
}
function clicked1(clickInfo){
//If click on blue go to green
if(clickInfo.target == Azul && texto.text == "Azul"){
    trace("Correto");
    texto.text = "Verde";
    Azul.visible = false;
}else{
    vidaa();
    vida.text = "Vidas: " + vidas;
    trace("Incorecto");
}
}
function clicked2(clickInfo){
//If click on green go to yellow
if(clickInfo.target == Verde && texto.text == "Verde"){
    trace("Correto");
    texto.text = "Amarelo";
    Verde.visible = false;
}else{
    vidaa();
    vida.text = "Vidas: " + vidas;
    trace("Incorecto");
}
}
function clicked3(clickInfo){
//If click on yellow go to pink
if(clickInfo.target == Amarelo && texto.text == "Amarelo"){
    trace("Correto");
    texto.text = "Rosa";
    Amarelo.visible = false;
}else{
    vidaa();
    vida.text = "Vidas: " + vidas;
    trace("Incorecto");
}
}
function clicked4(clickInfo){
//If click on pink go to orange
if(clickInfo.target == Rosa && texto.text == "Rosa"){
    trace("Correto");
    texto.text = "Laranja";
    Rosa.visible = false;
}else{
    vidaa();
    vida.text = "Vidas: " + vidas;
    trace("Incorecto");
}
}
function clicked5(clickInfo){
//If click on orange go to win the game
if(clickInfo.target == Laranja && texto.text == "Laranja"){
    trace("Correto");
    texto.text = "Parabéns";
    Laranja.visible = false;
}else{
    vidaa();
    vida.text = "Vidas: " + vidas;
    trace("Incorecto");
}

}


function vidaa(){
vidas -=1;
if (vidas == 0){
    gotoAndStop(2);
}
}
```

Comment: If you had ideas and how to compress the code write

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I wanted to see if I could get more compact

Comment: or you can put this in one function but there are a problem

Comment: please indent your code properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (completely untested though :)

```
// all colors in the order they will appear
var colors:Array = ["Vermelho", "Azul", "Verde", "Amarelo"] // add all other colors here

// assign a name to each button that is exactly the same as in the colors array - on click you will read that name and see if it matching the current color
// I believe there is a way to set the name in the Flash IDE as well in the object properties, but I don't remember anymore
vermelho.name = "Vermelho";
vermelho.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

vermelho.name = "Azul";
Azul.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

Verde.name = "Verde";
Verde.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

// current color index in the array (first color "Vermelho" is at position 0, we will start at -1 so the next color will be 0)
var currentIndex:int = -1;

// start the game, this will show the first color
showNextColor();

function onClick(event:MouseEvent)
{
    // check if the button name matches the current color
    if(event.target.name == colors[currentIndex])
    {
        trace("Correto");
        event.target.visible = false;
        showNextColor();
    }
    else
    {
        vidaa();
        vida.text = "Vidas: " + vidas;
        trace("Incorecto");
    }
}


// gets the current color from the array and displays it
private function showNextColor()
{
    // check if we have any colors left to show in the array
    if(currentIndex < colors.length - 1)
    {
        // if yes increase the index and show next color
        currentIndex++;
        texto.text = colors[currentIndex];
    }
    else
    {
        // otherwise the user have guessed all colors, do something here
        texto.text = "You are awesome!";
    }
}
```